# How can we add constraint on a function mapping such that each value in domain is mapped to only $1$ value of range in the universe?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I have a surjective function, given as

$$(\forall y \in Y)(\exists x \in X): f(x)=y.$$

Suppose, I have values in the domain $X = \{1,2,3\}$ and values in the range $Y = \{x,y,z\}$.

I want a function mapping such that each value of $X$ can be assigned to any value in $Y$ but then each value of $X$ must be assigned to that value of $Y$.

E.g. output can have either $\{\{1,x\}, \{2,x\}, \{3,x\}\}$ or $\{\{1,y\}, \{2,y\}, \{3,y\}\}$ or $\{\{1,z\}, \{2,z\}, \{3,z\}\}$.

I am relatively new to the set theory and I am totally clueless here as how can I define constraints on a function mapping, and I am using set notation to formally define my programming logics.

Comment: Do you mean so called constant functions i.e. $\forall x \in X, f(x)=c$, where $c$ is some value in range?

Comment: @zkutch kind of yes but it's a little bit more flexible than a convential constant function in a sense that, we have many constants so it's like choosing one 1 constant out of many constants.

Comment: In which is flexibility? If range $|Y|=m$, then you can have exactly $m$ constant functions - do you mean this?

Comment: Functions do not output.